# Coldfusion with spreadsheet to clone an existing sheet as a template for a new sheet

Tags: excel, coldfusion, spreadsheet

I am using coldfusion with spreadsheet, is that any way or function I can use to duplicate/clone/copy an existing sheet (act like template) in a workbook, and use it as a template for a new sheet in another workbook?

Comment: You can read spreadsheet1 into a query and use the query to create spreadsheet2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a coldFusion tag for that namely **cfspreadsheet**. You can use this function to read existing spreadsheet and create coldfusion object of that spreadsheet. You can use this object to create new sheets, update existing sheet. 
Please check [documentation of cfspreadsheet](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec17cba-7f87.html)

Comment: For additional functionality, see also [spreadsheet functions](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Spreadsheet+functions). For example, you could read in a sheet with [SpreadSheetRead](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/SpreadsheetRead). Modify it and save it to another file.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, now I am able to create new sheet and subsequent new sheet with the template using cfspreadsheetread, write, update and spreadsheetaddrow. But I face another problem, the cfspreadsheetread function is unable to read/store my template page title setting (I've set it to repeat some rows) to the object. When I try to print preview, this error prompt "Print titles must be contiguous and complete rows or columns". I check in the new excel file the page title setting is blank but in the template the value is already set and tested print with no problem. Please help.

Comment: @Adrienne, can you post your code and image of error. It will be helpful for me to help you.